# DevOps automated permission assignment in securitygroup does not work with Power Automate

Tags: http, azure-devops, permissions, power-automate

I am currently working on a process automation for Azure DevOps with Power Automate and I have a problem with automated permissions assignment in DevOps security groups at project level. I followed the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access-control-entries/set-access-control-entries?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&tabs=HTTP).
I first looked up which security namespace id and which bit I need and then I queried the group descriptor of the security group in which I want to change the permissions. Then I used the security namespace id (in my case 52d39943-cb85-4d7f-8fa8-c6baac873819), the bit (in my case 65536, to rename a project)
and the group descriptor in an HTTP request just like in the documentation.
I get a positive response from the server. The permission is also entered in the ACL, but nothing changes in the DevOps security group unfortunately. I also checked that it is not a display error in DevOps. Therefore i added a user to the devops security group and checked if he had the permission i just changed, but he didnt.

Do you happen to know anything about this?

Http request to change permission with postman:
[image: Http request to change permission with postman]

Http request to change permission with Power Automate:
[image: Http request to change permission with Power Automate]

Comment: We need to see a lot more information to help. Probably your relevant flow steps in Power Automate, for starters.

Comment: Thank you! i changed the post and added pictures